# Setting multiple class variables sourced from Firebase inside viewWillAppear and use them to populate tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried to denormalize my Firebase data as much as possible so in order to populate my `tableView` I need to get data from three different references and then use this data to populate my table. I am loading the data in `viewWillAppear` and I am trying to assign them to class variables. If I print the class variables it seems that outside of the observe the variables I am trying to set are still nil, but inside the observe the variables are populated with data. I am struggling to understand how to preserve the values in these variables for the entire class. Here is my code:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var words = [String]()
var imageURLs = [String]()
var correct = [Bool]()


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let ID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
        if let game = gameID {
            let correctRef = Database.database().reference().child("correct").child(ID).child(game)
            let photosRef = Database.database().reference().child("photos").child(ID).child(game)
            let wordsRef = Database.database().reference().child("words").child(ID).child(game)

            correctRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for child in snapshot.children {
                    if let snap = child as? DataSnapshot {
                        if let correctVal = snap.value as? Bool {
                            self.correct.append(correctVal)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            //This print has values
                            print(self.correct)
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            //This print is an empty array.
            print(self.correct)

            photosRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for child in snapshot.children {
                    if let snap = child as? DataSnapshot {
                        if let url = snap.value as? String {
                            self.imageURLs.append(url)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

            wordsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for child in snapshot.children {
                    if let snap = child as? DataSnapshot {
                        if let word = snap.value as? String {
                            self.words.append(word)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("ListTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ListTableViewCell

    let word = self.words[indexPath.row]
    cell.wordLabel.text = word
    let corr = correct[indexPath.row]
    cell.correctLabel.text = corr

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Where are you using these variables outside of the observe methods?

Comment: Sorry I am then using them in cellForRowAt. But even if I try to put a print(words) outside of the observe  in viewWillAppear the arrays are empty

Comment: I have edited my code with an example

Comment: Can you please show the `cellForRowAt` method? and please also tell that you only need these variables in `cellForRowAt` method?

Comment: You are seeing an empty array outside `observe` methods because these methods are `async` which means that they run only when callback is called from inside the firebase methods, your print outside is called first then your print inside the observe method is called

Comment: So the data is being stored correctly in those class variables?

Comment: yes , it is being added correctly,

Comment: Ah okay I am starting to get it. I added a viewWillDisappear just to test and printed the arrays there and yes it seems the arrays are as they should be. I will research more on `async`. Do you think the way I have it coded is a good way to go about loading and refreshing the data?

Comment: Yes you should see `async` , and the approach depends on your usecases, I myself is not that experienced but it seems right, you want to get fresh data every time the view appears on the screen, lastly I would suggest using `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }` inside your observe methods since it is a UI update so it must run on the main thread.